# Do these non-homotopic maps induce the same map in reduced homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-verification, homology-cohomology

Consider two maps $f, g: X\to Y$, where $X=Y=\{ 0, 1 \}$ with discrete topology, $f$ is the identity and $g$ maps everything to 0. Then it's clear that $\widetilde{H}_0(X;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and all the other groups are zero. The maps $f$ and $g$ cannot be homotopic, as they are not equal. I want to calculate explicitly what $f_\sharp, g_\sharp: \widetilde{H}_0(X)\to \widetilde{H}_0(Y)$ are. Now, it is easy to calculate that 
$$
\widetilde{H}_0(X)=\widetilde{H}_0(Y)=\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x_0, x_1]}{\mathbb{Z}[x_0-x_1]}\cong \mathbb{Z},
$$
where I think of $x_i$ as a map from the 0-simplex to $X$ with image $0$ or $1$ for $i=0$ or 1 respectively.Now, $f_\sharp$ is just the identity, but what about $g_\sharp$? We know that $\widetilde{H}_0 (X)$ is generated by $[x_0]$, which is easy to see: if I have $[nx_0 + mx_1]\in \widetilde{H}_0(X)$ then I can write it as
$$
[nx_0 + mx_1]=[(n+m)x_0+m(x_1-x_0)]=[(n+m)x_0].
$$
So, I get that $f_\sharp[n x_0+m x_0]=[(n+m)x_0]$. On the other hand, 
$$
g_\sharp[nx_0+mx_1]=[(n+m) x_0],
$$
straight from the definition. Did I get this right? Do we get $f_\sharp=g_\sharp$?

Answer (score 0):

[Note that you should write something like $\mathbb{Z}\{x_0,x_1\}$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}[x_0,x_1]$, since the latter usually means the polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$ in $x_0$ and $x_1$.]

The definition of the reduced homology is not the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}\{x_0,x_1\}$ by the subgroup generated by $x_0-x_1$; rather, it is the *subgroup* of $\mathbb{Z}\{x_0,x_1\}$ which is the kernel of the "augmentation" homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}$ that sends both $x_0$ and $x_1$ to $1$.  In general you would also have to mod out relations coming from the $1$-simplices in your space (you would mod out $x_0-x_1$ if there was a path from $x_0$ to $x_1$, but in this case there are no nonconstant $1$-simplices so you don't have to mod anything out.  So $\widetilde{H}_0(X)=\widetilde{H}_0(Y)$ is just the group $\mathbb{Z}\{x_0-x_1\}$ (since the kernel of the augmentation is freely generated by $x_0-x_1$).  When you compute $f_\#$ and $g_\#$ from this definition, you will find that $f_\#\neq g_\#$.